# Adding values to the contents of an array

Tags: java, arrays

I have an array called `x=points`. With in this array are ten coordinates (the `x` part of them anyway). I want to add a value of `10 * c` to each of the points within the array. Also, this is in java.

How might I do this?

```
for (int c = 0; c <= 9; c++) {
for(int k = 0; k <= 9; k++) {
        if (k%2 == 0) {
            xpoints[k] = (int) (20*Math.cos((k*3.14/5)+3*3.14/2)) +60;
            ypoints[k] = (int) (20*Math.sin((k*3.14/5)+3*3.14/2)) +60;
        } else if (k%2 == 1) {
            xpoints[k] = (int) (8*Math.cos((k*3.14/5)+3*3.14/2)) +60;
            ypoints[k] = (int) (8*Math.sin((k*3.14/5)+3*3.14/2)) +60;
            }
        }
    // This is where I am having trouble
    xpoints[] = xpoints + 5*c;
    g.fillPolygon(xpoints, ypoints, npoints);
}
```

Comment: Which programming language is this?

Comment: Sorry, this is in java

Comment: where is your code ?

Comment: what is the type of `xpoints[]` ?

Comment: tell me so that i can help you

Comment: so you just need a for loop that goes from 0 to the last index of the array and `xpoints[i] = xpoints[i] + 10 * c;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
> // This is where I am having trouble
> xpoints[] = xpoints + 5*c;
> ```

To update a value at index `i` within the array, access it by its index and re-assign the updated value:

```
xpoints[i] = xpoints[i] + 10 * c;
```

Or shorter:

```
xpoints[i] += 10 * c;
```

To loop over the entire array and update each single value:

```
for (int i = 0; i < xpoints.length; i++) {
  xpoints[i] += 10 * c;
}
```

Or use Java 8 streams:

```
xpoints = Arrays.stream(xpoints).map(xpoint -> xpoint + 10 * c).toArray();
```